# I have a webcam (041e:401e) with Linux kernel 5.12.5; is the webcam obsolete?

Tags: camera

- `uname -r`: `5.12.5-arch1-1`
- `lsusb -s 001:007`: `Bus 001 Device 007: ID 041e:401e Creative Technology, Ltd Webcam NX Pro`
- Yesterday my Zoom app recognized my camera but not today.
- Noticed `/dev/video*` not found.
- Found it used driver: spca5xx/LE gspca v4l1/v4l2
- Found [this website.](http://mxhaard.free.fr/download.html)
- Found somebody made us Arch user repository package (AUR) but not available anymore.
- Downloaded [gspcav1-20071224.tar.gz](http://mxhaard.free.fr/spca50x/Download/gspcav1-20071224.tar.gz) but not have built it yet, as I am afraid of it destroying the kernel, as it was originally intended for 2.6.11+; what about 3.x.x or later?

Comment: In the newest kernel, [gspca](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/media/usb/gspca) is available, so I am surprised it's not in your 5.12.5. Check your available modules; if necessary, use your distro's ways to build a kernel and enabled it. The chances of your old source file working with a modern kernel are very very small.

Comment: Thanks @dirkt, found both gspca and v4l2 in my `/usr/lib/modules/*/kernel/`!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I did not see the repository of the kernel at first.

Comment: You can answer your own question (and accept the answer), in particular if you include details how to make your webcam work with those modules - for example, you may still have to include the `041e:401e` in the source and recompile it if it doesn't get picked up automatically.

Comment: It's .ko.xz file, not .ko! Also seems it runs with gspca_zc3xx.ko; but I need more time to learn to load it.

Comment: Use `modprobe` to load a module, and `modinfo` to see for which USB ids it should load automatically, and `dmesg` to look for potential errors.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not obsolete, as @dirkt pointed out; [refer this to check what drivers are required for your webcam.](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/Documentation/admin-guide/media)
2. Hypothesis of the reason why Zoom recognized my webcam yesterday but not today; because I connected my webcam before booting yesterday, but not today.
3. Then the hypothesis seemed to be correct.
4. `lsusb`, then check webcam ID such as 041e:401e. In this case 041e stands for vendor ID; 401e for product.
5. Look for what driver is required; mine requires zc3xx, as in [this](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/media/gspca-cardlist.rst).
6. `lsmod | grep 'your driver name here'`. On my environment, for example:

```
gspca_zc3xx 61440 0
gspca_main 32768 1 gspca_zc3xx
:
:
videodev ... ... gspca_main,gspca_zc3xx,...
```

The 4th column stands for "Used by".

7. Edit `/etc/modules-load.d/virtio-net.conf`:

```
# plz load webcam (creative)
videodev
videobuf2_common
# and so on
gspca_main
gspca_zc3xx
```

I thought if order matters; I wrote in reverse order of step 6.

8. Try rebooting, then unplug your webcam, and login.
9. Finally, try `lsmod`, connecting and unconnecting your webcam, and `ls /dev/video*`.